# Переопределенная цель постоянно выполняется

Tags: c++, makefile

Мне необходимо использовать make следующим образом:

```
bin ?= bar                                                                      

all: ${bin}                                                                     

objects := 1.o 2.o                                                              

$(objects): %.o: ./%.cpp                                                        
▸   g++ -c  $< -o $@                                                            

foo: FORCE                                                                      
▸   bin=foo\                                                                    
▸   ▸   $(MAKE)·                                                                

${bin}: ${objects}                                                              
▸   g++  ${objects} -o ${bin}                                                  

FORCE:
```

То есть bar - цель по умолчанию, а make foo вызывает команду make второй раз с переменной bin=foo. Проблема заключается в том что цель

```
${bin}: ${objects}                                                              
▸   g++  ${objects} -o ${bin}
```

запускается(происходит линковка) каждый раз при вызове make foo, даже когда в линковке нет необходимости.
Эту проблему можно избежать если переименовать цель вызывающую make второй раз:

```
foo_bla_bla: FORCE                                                                      
▸   bin=foo\                                                                    
▸   ▸   $(MAKE)
```

тогда линковка происходит только тогда, когда это нужно. Но мне необходимо, чтобы имена у этих целей были одинаковые. В этом случае при вызове make из цели foo происходит переопределение цели. Почему переопределение цели влечет за собой выполнение цели `${bin}` независимо от состояния зависимостей?

Comment: что-то хитрое ты творишь... это действительно необходимо зачем-то или проосто хочется, чтоб было «именно так»?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, просто по make foo надо собрать такой же бинарник, но с другими флагами и библиотеками. Но структура собрки такая же как и для bar, чтобы не дублировать код, сделано так. Но make не мой все равно, нужен именно этот вариант

Comment: дык, просто `FORCE` убери — он же и заставляет пересобираться при повторном запуске, а при первом он не нужен... но это всё равно достаточно грязный хак... я бы не выпендривался и сделал `foo` нормальной целью...

Comment: @Fat-Zer при повторном запуске `foo: FORCE`  игнорируется, потому что есть цель с таким же именем, только ниже (`${bin}: ${objects}` )

Comment: игнорируется правило сборки `bin=foo $(MAKE)`, а зависимость цели `foo: FORCE` — учитывается... по крайней мере так действует гнутый вариант `make`...

Comment: Да именно, спасибо! я почему то считал что переопределяется вся цель, а не только рецепт. только что мне ответили так же в английской версии.

Comment: При первом нужен `FORCE`, чтобы в обязательном порядке вызвать `$ bin=foo $(MAKE)`

Comment: для цели без зависимости оно и так всегда будет вызываться...

Comment: Решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076672/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f?noredirect=1#comment1849474_1076672

Comment: @Fet-Zer, да, если бы файла foo не существовало, он и является нужным бинарником

Answer (score 1):

при запуске с параметром `foo` программа *make* (следуя рецепту) запускается повторно, и в этот момент у вас получаются **два** рецепта для одной и той же цели `foo`. о чём программа и предупреждает:

> GNUmakefile:15: warning: overriding recipe for target 'foo'

выполняется только последний из дублирующихся рецептов, о чём программа также
предупреждает:

> GNUmakefile:11: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'foo'

игнорируются лишь рецепты, но не пререквизиты, т.е. пререквизит `FORCE` остаётся «в силе».

потому рецепт и выполняется принудительно, а время обновления «реальных» пререквизитов не учитывается.

---

чтобы максимально сохранить требующуюся вам логику поведения с минимальными «затратами», достаточно переименовать имя цели, т.е. строку

```
foo: FORCE
```

заменить, например, на (пререквизит `FORCE` в этом случае уже не нужен)

```
update.foo:
```

и для обновления файла `foo` выполнять не

```
$ make foo
```

а

```
$ make update.foo
```